# How to change the caret offset in a rich text editor textarea?

Tags: javascript, textarea, selection, caret, wysihtml5

I have a [wysihtml](https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml) rich text editor. If certain conditions are met I want to change the offset of the caret.

Because a wysithtml textarea is not really a `textarea` div (it's just a regular div) I can't use the common textarea strategies to move the caret. But after some experimentation I found out that treating it as a [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) enables me to work with it as a textarea.

From what I read the correct method to change the caret offset is [Range.setStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart), but I can't figure out how to use it. Anyone who can help me?

I have set up [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg6md8uL/). Try (in Firefox) to move the caret to offset 27. Then the value of the editor will change, and the caret will move to offset 0. But how do I move the caret to e.g. offset 35?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg6md8uL/2/) to work like you want.
This is the part i modified :

```js
if (offsets.start_offset == 27) {
    editor.setValue("This is first line.<br>This is another second line.", true);

   /* START OF MODIFICATION */

      var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      range.selectNodeContents(textarea);

        var fromPos = 27;
        var lenTotal = ( textarea.textContent || textarea.innerText ).length;
        var lenCurTextNode = range.endContainer.lastChild.nodeValue.length;
        var lenNewWord= 'another '.length ;

        var newPos = ( fromPos - (lenTotal - lenCurTextNode) ) + lenNewWord;


      range.setStart(range.startContainer.lastChild , newPos);
      range.setEnd(range.endContainer.lastChild , newPos);

  /* END OF MODIFICATION */

      var offsets = getOffsets(textarea);
    console.log("I want offsets.start_offset to be 35, but it is " + offsets.start_offset)
  } else {
    console.log("Offset is from " + offsets.start_offset + " to " + offsets.end_offset );
  }
```

You have to deal with the `textNode` to create a range of text characters and not whith the HTMLElement.
It was for that, your `Range.setStart()`, had no effect, it was 'ranging' divs !

In your sample textarea is a div in which you need to find each textNode and interact with them.
In the code above `range.endContainer.lastChild` is a textNode *(in reality the lastChild of textarea)*.

Hope this will help you !

---

*Tested with Firefox*